# What are some of the best circuit separations that we know of and that we suspect?

Tags: complexity-theory

We know that $\mathsf{non-uniformAC^0\subsetneq PSPACE}$, $\mathsf{non-uniformACC^0\subsetneq NEXP}$. We know that $\mathsf{uniformACC^0=PH}$ is a possibility.

What are some of circuit separations that we know of?

What are some circuit separations that seem farthest apart but cannot be separated? By this question I mean that even though $\mathsf{uniformTC^0\subsetneq PH}$ is a possibility, an answer with  $\mathsf{uniformACC^0\subsetneq PH}$ suffices since $\mathsf{uniformACC^0\subsetneq uniformTC^0}$ is hypothesized.

Comment: We know that $AC^0 \neq TC^0$.

Answer (score 3):

For all uniform classes $\operatorname{UF}$, for essentially any non-uniform class $\operatorname{NU}$, one will

have $\: \operatorname{NU} \not\subseteq \operatorname{UF} \:$, $\:$ since $\operatorname{NU}$ should be uncountable and $\operatorname{UF}$ is countable.

("Proof:" $\;\;\;$ By any reasonable definition of being uniform, for a language to be in $\operatorname{UF}$

there must be something in a particular at-most-countable set of things such that the

thing determines the language, so there are at most countably many languages in $\operatorname{UF}$.

On the other hand, for each subset $S$ of $\:\{\hspace{-0.03 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2,\hspace{-0.03 in}3,...\hspace{-0.04 in}\}\:$,$\:$ the definition of $\operatorname{NU}$ should

mean that [the language consisting of exactly the strings whose length is in $S\hspace{.02 in}$] is in $\operatorname{NU}$.

In that case, since those languages are all different, $\operatorname{UF}$ will be uncountable.

"Therefore," one will have $\: \operatorname{NU} \not\subseteq \operatorname{UF} \;$.)

In particular, $\;\;\; \mathsf{non-uniformAC^0} \: \not\subseteq \: \operatorname{PSPACE} \;\;\;$ and

$\mathsf{non-uniformACC^0} \: \not\subseteq \: \operatorname{NEXP} \;\;\;$, $\;\;\;$ so both claims in your initial sentence are false.

It is far more interesting to ask which uniform classes

are subsets of which non-uniform classes.

[$\operatorname{REG}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:R#reg) $\: \not\subseteq \: \mathsf{non-uniformAC^0} \;\;\;$, $\;\;\;$ since $\;\;\;$ [parity $\: \not\in \: \mathsf{non-uniformAC^0}$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019011003504) $\:\:\:\:$.

$\operatorname{NEXP} \: \not\subseteq \: \mathsf{non-uniformACC^0} \;\;\;$; $\;\;\;$ which [your question on cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31290/6973) was asking about.

[$\operatorname{MA_{exp}}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#maexp) $\cap \hspace{.03 in}\operatorname{co-MA_{exp}}$ $\: \not\subseteq \:$ [$\operatorname{P/poly}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppoly) $\;\;\;$, $\;\;\;$ by [page 16 of this paper](http://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui/Ulmer_Informatik_Berichte/1994/UIB_1994-11.pdf#page=16).

[$\operatorname{AM_{exp}}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#amexp) $\: \not\subseteq \:$ [$\operatorname{(NP\cap coNP)/poly}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#npiconppoly) $\;\;\;$, $\;\;\;$ by [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0020019003004460/1-s2.0-S0020019003004460-main.pdf?_tid=c3830bfe-ee11-11e4-a51b-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1430272259_b81c933f49fc08903b34cf740d7739f5). $\;\;\;\;\;$ (The right-hand-side of

the last non-containment is likely smaller than the class one would think it means.)

[This paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48686-0_21) shows that [$\operatorname{MA_{exp}}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#maexp) can't be decided by circuits with "half-exponential" size.